# Connect audio output to recording device

Tags: audio

I am working with the 9V sound recording module from Radio Shack. It comes with an electret mic, but I am trying to figure out how to connect headphone output or computer line out output to the mic wires (if possible)

[Link to device on Radio Shack's Web site](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2102855)

When in recording mode, the voltage to the mic seems to be about 3.3 volts.

Is there a circuit to make this connection and have sound files 'played' to the sound module from an mp3 player, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Manual here](http://www.radioshack.com/graphics/uc/rsk/Support/ProductManuals/2761323A_PM_EN.pdf) such as it is.

Disconnect microphone wires AFTER noting which wire goes where.
A photo that is detailed enough and sharp enough to allow you to tell is a good idea.
Putting a copy of the photo on disk somewhere with a file name that tells you where it is "is wise"
Emailing a copy to yourself using a persistent online email account (eg gmail and many more) with key words in the message and subject line is overkill and latterly often welcome.

Connect 2 wires to where mic went with a 100 uF electrolytic cap in one wire.

Try connecting phone or line audio source to the above input - start with volume turned down, and turn up progressively while listening to result.

If level is far too high add two resistors to form an attenuator. Value shown below are a start - abut 11:1 attenuation.

Attentuation = R2/(R1+r2) if capacitor impedance is small compared to resistor values.
Making values too low (eg 10 Ohm, 1 Ohm) loads input excessively and capacotor impedance may be too high.  .
Making values too high eg 1 megOhm/100k causes impedance matching problems at recorder.
R1 and R2 could be a single eg 10k potentiometer with output at wiper.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB87lv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. In the circuit provided, is the mp3 player on the left side, and the sound recorder on the right side?

Comment: okay, I just put this together and it works pretty well! I don't understand enough audio to understand exactly *why* it works, and it seemed like pushing 3V back into my player was a bad idea.

Comment: @gec, the capacitor blocks DC and only allows the AC component to pass so the above is safe. You should be able to check with your multimeter that the 3.3V 'disappears'.

Comment: +1 - Hi Russell, an excellent answer as is to be expected.

Comment: Link to the manual now is dead

Comment: Question: If I have stereo audio output with L (tip), R (ring), ground (sleeve) and a mic in with mono (tip), +5V (ring), ground (sleeve), how to wire? Are the bottom two wires in your schematic the two grounds? And would you combine L+R together and pass this into the top left of your schematic (to the capacitor)? And should you short-circuit the +5V to ground, or not connect it at all?

Comment: @Qqwy You can connect either one channel to the mono in OR combine them at the risk of annoying the source (ie MAY be OK) or could combine using a series resistor in L & R (say 1K in each to start),. Gnd-Gnd is OK. The cap will block DC. I don't know why mic-in needs 5V but as described, if it does, it can't have it. Whether to float or ground depends on what it is for. Floating would usually be safer than hard grounding. Grounding with  say 1K probably safest. BUT specific equipment needs to be known.